# how to serve pre-flight request from web service

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, same-origin-policy, cors

I have a web service which works over `GET`. To access this web service, some custom headers need to be passed.

When I try to access the web service from javascript code with `GET` method, the request method is getting changed to `OPTIONS`. (the domain is different)

I read some articles to find out that a request with Custom headers will be pre-flighted and in that case before the actual method call, a request with OPTIONS method will be made to the server.

But my problem is after the `OPTIONS` call, the real method (i.e `GET`) is not being invoked.

The `OPTIONS` call is returning the status as 401.

I doubt this is because my web-service supports `GET` only. How can I solve the problem?
Kindly help.
(My code is working fine with IE but not with other browser e.g. Chrome)

Comment: Based on your example, I would be more concerned that IE *is* allowing the request.

Comment: I have to get the things work over chrome or other browsers. Because finally I have to use the smartphone browsers to get the things done.

Comment: In that case, you should confirm that the mobile browser's support `CORS`. Here's a good list: http://caniuse.com/cors

Answer (score 4):

Two things to check for (with no idea what your server-side language / technique is):

1. Are you including `OPTIONS` as a valid method in your `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`? Example:

   ```
   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS
   ```
2. Are the custom headers that your request sending being returned to the browser as allowed?
   Example:

   ```
   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER
   ```

The remote server has to return both of these (and most definitely the second one) before any secure, standards-compliant browser (ie not older versions of IE), will allow the non-origin response to come through.

So, if you wanted to implement this at the HTTP server level and keep your web-service portable, you might try the following:

We'll assume your web-service URL is `http://example.org/service` and that the path to service is `/srv/www/service`

If you are running Apache 2.0, the syntax to append headers is `add`, on 2.2, use `set`.

So, you would modify `/srv/www/service/.htaccess` with:

```
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-MY_CUSTOM_HEADER1,X-MY_CUSTOM_HEADER2"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Of course, the `mod_headers` Apache module needs to be on for the above to work. Also, setting the allow-origin to the wild card is risky, and it will actually cause the request to fail if you are sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header (can't use wild cards in that case).  Also, with the `SetEnvIf` mod for Apache, you could fine tune the htaccess file to only return the headers when appropriate, rather than for all requests to that directory.

Comment: but I have a cxf web service. Are you saying that I have to allow the methods to work using OPTIONS along with GET ?

Comment: @GET
@Produces({ "application/json" })
@Path("/getData")
public CustomDTO getData() {...}

Comment: The web service shouldn't matter.  Are you using Apache as the actual HTTP server (which manages the HTTP headers prior to serving up the web service)?  If so, you should be able to modify (in `.htaccess` file, I presume) how requests are handled and responded.

Comment: so, there won't be any change in the web service code. The web server has to be configured to handle the preflight requests. Am i correct?

Comment: I am using tomcat 6.0 with apache CXF engine to create the web services. How can I serve the preflight OPTION requests ?

Comment: I'm no sure if CXF or Tomcat can (easily) return HTTP response codes. I know that if I wrote the web-service with PHP, I could issue out HTTP headers before any other methods were called using the `header()` function, so I imagine that there is some way that the service or the servlet *could* do it, but in the interest of portability, I would go with having the HTTP server itself do it. I'll update my answer to reflect how this might be done via `.htaccess`, assuming Tomcat is not between Apache and the web-service.