# Cross domain ajax and WCF

Tags: ajax, wcf

Is WCF allowing cross-domain ajax functionality?

I have a WCF project (localhost:53763) and a web application (localhost:50238) in C#. I tried to access WCF in my web application ajax call. I got error in console that

OPTIONS localhost:53763/WCFTest.svc/xml/1122 405 (Method Not Allowed) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:53763/WCFTest.svc/xml/1122. Origin localhost:50238 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Then I tried it by added the WCF project in IIS. Then also I got error same as above

OPTIONS http://www.WCFTest.com/WCFTest.svc/xml/111 405 (Method Not Allowed) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.WCFTest.com/WCFTest.svc/xml/111. Origin localhost:50238 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: these links might help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314255/how-to-serve-pre-flight-request-from-web-service

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this line to your functions:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

There are several options to decorate every request, but I cannot find the correct interface for that.